# In windows 10, How can I disable UEFI Boot?

Tags: boot, windows-10

I have known from previous search that I can disable the UEFI Boot "Secure Boot" through tapping shift + restart and then, the window of (continue, Troubleshoot, Turn Of Your PC) should appear, then I should choose Troubleshoot and get some options including advanced options which I should click and choose disable UEFI Boot from there. But actually what happens is that when I click on Troubleshoot from the first windows I only get Startup settings and I never see the other options. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Advanced Startup will allow you to get to your UEFI shell.  of course if you disable UEFI mode, then Windows 10 won't boot, until you **reinstall** Windows mode in legacy mode.

Comment: @Ramhound I think they only want to disable Secure Boot

Comment: @Moab - I would agree with you normally except that the question's title specifically indicates "How can I disable UEFI Boot".  Since UEFI Boot is not **Secure Boot**, considering **Secure Boot** is simply a feature of a specific revision of the UEFI speciication, what the author specifically wants needs to be clarified by the author themselfs.

Comment: @Ramhound agree its a poorly written question.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable Secure Boot from BIOS. Restart your PC, and when it starts booting up again (the very first couple seconds), press your setup-entry key (depending on your motherboard manufacturer, it's usually F10, F2, F8 or Escape - consult this website for more info http://boot-keys.org/). You should enter BIOS, if it doesn't happen, just restart and try again. If I remember correctly, the Secure Boot option is in Advanced tab. Toggle it, then save & exit and that's it.